# Many To Many field and request.user not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to do a very simple request :

**My model**

```
class LogBook(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(
    max_length=50, verbose_name="Nom du registre de maintenance"
)
members = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name="Utilisateurs", related_name = 'member')
```

**Now if I tried in my view :**

```
if request.user == log.members
```

To check whether or not the user belongs to the LogBook it does not deny access, any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`log.members` is a *manager*, it is not a single user, nor is it even a `QuerySet`. You can check if this users exists with:

```
if request.user in log.members.all():
    # …
```

or with a `.filter(…)`:

```
if log.members.filter(pk=request.user.pk).exists():
    # …
```